# Upper-bounding $\exp \log^{d} \frac{\log n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, logarithms, approximation, polylogarithm

How would you upper-bound this expression? 
$$f(n, d) = \exp \log^{d} \frac{\log n}{n}$$

If $d  = 1 $ this woulld simplify to $\frac{\log n}{n}$.
Any suggestions on how to upperbound it?

Notation clarification: $\log^x y = (\log y)^x$.

Comment: If $d=1$, the expression would simplify to $\frac{\log n}{n}$.

Comment: Also, since you are using $n$, am I to assume that the function is a mapping from $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @SatD yes, and yes.